# Can't initiate working with OpenNTF Domino API, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse, hcl-notes

I am working with DDE version: Release 10.0.1FP4

Then I downloaded from OpenNTF the 6 mei 2019   10.0.1 version of ODA. installation in DDE went fine.

On my nsf in the xsp.properties I referenced the plugin as a dependency:

```
xsp.library.depends=org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspLibrary
```

Then I created my first java class:

```
package se.acme.oda;

public class HelloWorld {   
    private void tryMe(){       
        Session sess = Factory.getSession(SessionType.CURRENT);
        Database db = sess.getDatabase("", "database.nsf", true);       
    }
}
```

When I build my project I get the following errors:

- Database cannot be resolved to a type
- Factory cannot be resolved
- Session cannot be resolved to a type
- SessionType cannot be resolved to a variable

Can someone guide me through the process of starting to use the ODA plugin?

Should I import the library in my java class or? (tried but did not help). Looks like it can not find the installation?

Comment: Do you see org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspLibrary as an option in the XPage Libraries section ofn the Page Generation tab in Xsp Properties? or did you add the xsp.library.depends line manually?

Comment: And add the correct imports to your java class:
import org.openntf.domino.Database;
import org.openntf.domino.Session;
import org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory;
import org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory.SessionType;

If you get an error with that, try a project > clean. When ODA has just been enabled in a database that's something needed (once).

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten I see the library as an option. In the source I noticed the notation after selecting the option

Comment: @MarkLeusink I added the imports but it results to the additional error: The import org.openntf cannot be resolved

Comment: @Malin check if these fixes help: https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/058650E080E352178525832B00519D2C

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten I added an extra entry for the Target PLatform in my preferences and restarted my client and the errors disappeared after a new clean of the project. Thank you very much!